# Why does this expression not work as expected in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, apply

A newcomer to Lisp. I know that

```
(mapcar #'list '(1 2) '(3 4))
```

will give

```
'((1 3) (2 4))
```

and based on my understanding of how apply works, I expect

```
(apply #'(lambda (&rest x) (mapcar #'list x)) '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

to return the same result. Instead, I am getting

```
'(((1 2)) ((3 4)))
```

I am confused because

```
(apply #'append '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

gives me

```
'(1 2 3 4)
```

as expected. What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify it. Suppose you used `A` instead of `(1 2)`, and `B` instead of `(3 4)`:

```
(apply #'(lambda (&rest x) (mapcar #'list x)) '(A B))
```

Because `&rest x` takes all the arguments and packs them up as a list, so `x` has the value 
`(A B)`.
Then `mapcar` iterates twice, passing `A` to `list`, producing `(A)`, then it does the same with `B`. Then `mapcar` makes a list of those, producing `( (A) (B) )`

It's useful to put print statements in there to see what's going on.

Comment: Ah! OK, my misunderstanding was of &rest. Thank you!